# How do I calculate the cdf over this range? I'm very confused.

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't want the answer, I just want an explanation.

Say $F(x) = 0.25 x^2$ for $0 \leq x < 2$.

If $F(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 2$ and $F(x) = 0$ everywhere else, how would I calculate $P(X \leq 1.5)$?

Comment: @HalilDuru $P(X=2)$ does **not** equal $1$.

Comment: @HalilDuru  $P(X=2)=0$. In fact, $P(X=a) = 0$ for all choices of real number $a$.

Comment: @HalilDuru: No, $P(X=2)=F(2)-F(2-)=1-0.25\cdot 2^2=0$.

Comment: Yes .You are right.

Answer (score 5):

Recall the definition of the [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) $F_X(x)$.

> It is the probability $F_X(x):= \mathsf{Pr}\left(X \leqslant x \right)$. Thus $\mathsf{Pr}\left(X \leqslant 1.5 \right) = \underline{\phantom{F_X(1.5)}}$.

Comment: Can I use pdf formulas then, and just integrate from 0 to 1.5?

Comment: @DougSmith Do you know how to find the pdf (it is not given in the problem statement you provided us)? If so, do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus? and can you relate the fundamental theorem to what you propose to do: find the pdf and then integrate it from $0$ to $1.5$?

Comment: @DougSmith You do not need the pdf and you do not need to integrate. Follow Sasha's hint.

Comment: @DougSmith : It's silly to talk about integrating here.  You're making the problem immensely more complicated than it is.  $P(X\le1.5)$ is the same as $F(1.5)$ because THAT IS NOW cumulative distribution functions are defined.  Notice that $1.5$ is between $0$ and $2$, so $F(1.5) = 0.25(1.5^2)$.

Comment: @DougSmith : Definitely heed Byron Schmuland's comment.  You ignored Sasha's answer.  You have to read it.

Comment: Typo: "THAT IS HOW" . . . . .

Comment: @DougSmith Did you actually read Sasha's answer?